# To stop master-slave replication with MySQL, do I need to issue any commands to master?

Tags: mysql

I have two mySQL databases set up as master-slave. Do I need to issue a command to the master to stop this replication?

From previous posts I understand that I have to issue the following commands to slave:

```
stop slave
reset slave
```

And add skip-slave-start to my.cnf

This question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91814/how-do-i-completely-disable-mysql-replication

Addresses master-master. I'd like a similar answer for master-slave config please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Till `bin-log` is enabled on master and `server-id` is set, it can be a master to any slave as I know. You can set server-id of master to 0 for disabling replication from master side.

Check article on [mysql dev](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-masterbaseconfig.html)

Comment: thanks for your help - that's a good idea to change server-id

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to stop replication from the master to the slave, you don't have to do anything on the master.  The master can chug along happily.

Though you should note that the master will still have binary log going, but you'll probably want that. : )